# Distinguish TypeError triggered by wrong function arguments and triggered by function body

Tags: python, exception, typeerror

Consider

```
try:
    f(*args, **kwargs)
except TypeError:
    print "doh!"
```

The reason for `TypeError` in this case could a problem in function arguments, e.g. `f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'b'`. However, `TypeError` could also be raised due to a problem within the function body itself, e.g. `list indices must be integers, not str`.

**I wonder if there is a solid way in Python 2 in order to distinguish both cases (problem with arguments, problem in body).** Maybe some decorator-based approach?

Reasoning: I am implementing just another kind of job system. A job basically is a function. The arguments to this function could be derived from user input and go through a JSON serialization/deserialization process. I want the system to provide as exact error messages as possible to the user of the system. Hence, I would like the entity that controls job execution to be able to distinguish both sources of `TypeError`. Furthermore, I think this a very interesting problem itself.

I realize that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712475/how-to-check-if-a-typeerror-raised-from-mismatched-function-arguments basically is a duplicate of this question. However, the comment discussion there just stopped without any answers. I hope in this case it is okay to open my own question and reformulate the issue.

Comment: I think the only solution is to parse the error message or check the exception information in the `sys` module.
Anyway I think that you should be able to avoid this. If the function was called with the correct arguments then it should not raise a `TypeError`. Probably a `ValueError` could be used in most corner-cases.

Answer (score 1):

So I wouldn't do it the way since the internal error that you want to propagate up is a coding error, not an actual exception that needs to be caught.

That being said. I would introspect the error being thrown and and silence one and propagate the other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can solve this problem the following way:

**Step 1.** Create a custom exception (e.g. `AwfulTypeError`) for the *in-body TypeError* by subclassing `Exception`:

```
class AwfulTypeError(Exception):
    pass  # Or do something if necessary
```

**Step 2.** Wrap your *whole function body* in a `try` block and `except TypeError` for that block:

```
def my_function(a, b, c):
    try:
        # Some operations you need to do
        return (a + b) * c
    except TypeError as e:
        # We're doing stuff here in the next step
```

**Step 3.** On catching the original `TypeError` exception, re-raise it as an `AwfulTypeError` exception that you have specified before:

```
    except TypeError as e:
        raise AwfulTypeError(e)
```

Now you are able to distinguish the *argument TypeError*, which remains a `TypeError`, from the *in-body TypeError*, which is now of type `AwfulTypeError`.

**P.S.** I am more used to *Python 3*, so if I've messed something up with the *Python 2* syntax, feel free to notify me.